# Writing XML for dataset containing multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm getting 2 tables in my dataset.

I need to structure my XML as:

```
<MyRoot>
    <Settings>
        <Param1>value1</Param1>
        <Param2>value2</Param2>
        <Param3>value3</Param3>
    </Settings>
    <Books>
      <Book>
          <BookId>1000</BookId>
          <BookName>Book1</BookName>
      </Book>
      <Book>
          <BookId>2000</BookId>
          <BookName>Book2</BookName>
      </Book>
    </Books>
</MyRoot>
```

But when I use datSet.WriteXML(); I'm getting XML as:

```
<MyRoot>
    <Settings>
        <Param1>value1</Param1>
        <Param2>value2</Param2>
        <Param3>value3</Param3>
    </Settings>
    <Book>
       <BookId>1000</BookId>
       <BookName>Book1</BookName>
    </Book>
    <Book>
       <BookId>2000</BookId>
       <BookName>Book2</BookName>
    </Book>
</MyRoot>
```

So, I'm not able to add separate dataset name as "Books" to second table (dataSet.Tables[1]). Is there any way that I can do that?

I tried the below code:

```
dataSet = GetList();
dataSet.DataSetName = "MyRoot"; 
dataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "Settings"; 
dataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "Books"; 
StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter(); 
dataSet.WriteXml(swriter); 
string dsResult = swriter.ToString();
```

Thanks.

Comment: dataSet = GetList();
                dataSet.DataSetName = "MyRoot";
                dataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "Settings";
                dataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "Books";

                StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter();
                dataSet.WriteXml(swriter);
                string dsResult = swriter.ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to tell `DataSet.WriteXml` directly to write the XML in the way you want it, so you have two big options:

- Let `DataSet.WriteXml` write the XML and modify it afterwards.
- Write the serialization code yourself.

For both ways you have different options how to do it. In the first case you can

- Load the created XML into a `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` and restructure it via code.
- Transform your XML via XSLT (I would prefer that over the code solution)

The options in the second case should be obvious. If you create your own `XmlWriter` and use `DataTable.WriteXml` to write to it, you should be able to define your own format in a few lines of code.

To choose the right solution for your use case is up to you. I would probably go for the XSTL solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the original XML by some code like below.

```
string filename = "XmlDoc.xml";
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream (filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
ds.WriteXml(stream); 
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument("XmlDoc.xml");
XmlNode node1 = xmldoc.CreateNode("Books","Books");

foreach(XmlNode nd in xmldoc.Nodes) {
  if(node.value =="Book")   
    node1.AppendChild(nd);
}

xmldoc.Nodes.Add(node1);
xmldoc.SaveAs("newXmlDoc.Xml");
```